# Does Tractate Nedarim never mention the talmudic terminology 'Tanu Rabanan'?

Tags: talmud-gemara, words, tractate-nedarim

I heard that Nedarim is rare as a Tractate in that it completely omits usage of the phrase Tanu Rabanan (its purpose being the introduction of a well known Baraisa, followed by an amoraic discussion).

Is this true?

Comment: The language of Nedarim is slightly different from the rest of Shas.

Answer (score 1):

According to a Sefaria search, it never comes up. However, D'Tanu Rabanan comes up once on 27a.